# Brauer-Manin obstruction and Hasse principle

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, rational-points

I am looking for

1. varieties without $\mathbf{Q}$-rational points where the absence can be explained by the Brauer-Manin obstruction, but not by the absence of adelic points
2. varieties without $\mathbf{Q}$-rational points where the absence cannot be explained by the Brauer-Manin obstruction

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Everything you want (and a whole lot more) is here: A. N. Skorobogatov, Torsors and rational points. Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics, 144. Cambridge University Press, 2001.